# How thick is a computer RAM module?

Tags: pcb, mechanical, pc

I was just using a DDR3 RAM module as a feeler gauge and it fit the gap perfectly.

However, then I tried to find out how thick it actually is and I couldn't find any specs.

I'm assuming it's standard 1.6mm FR-4, but there must be a specification out there, right?

Comment: Find a datasheet for the socket and you will probably find the answer.

Comment: Is mechanical design off-topic? There is a "mechanical" tag and there are questions like [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353514/what-is-the-usable-area-for-connectors-of-a-pci-express-card-bracket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search gives you the answer you are looking for. the PCB is 1.27mm thick.
For the other mechanical dimensions see here at page 11
[DDR3 DIMM  Dimensions](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Micron%20Technology%20Inc%20PDFs/MT8JTF(128,256)64A_RevB.pdf).

[image: drawing]

Please note that not all manufacturers are equal, but in general these dimensions match the standard.

Comment: Nice find! I added a screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

[JEDEC](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZKVbgABcTAAJ:https://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/docs/4_20_28R24.pdf%20&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-b-ab) says:

> For DDR4 LP RDIMM reference designs with SDRAMs in a single row, a maximum package size of 11.0 mm
>   nominal width and 13.0 mm nominal height will be used. Individual reference designs may have different
>   requirement

Comment: That seems unrelated to the thickness of the PCB.

Comment: This seems to be talking about the individual SDRAM chip packages on the module.